# Prestashop slider not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Using Prestashop 1.6.1.0 i tried to use slider for price range in Prestashops blocklayered module but the prices won't update and this is the error thrown:

```
v_17_7c30367….js:2 Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; 
attempted to call method 'values'
```

I've read somewhere it's because an older version of jquery. This is the blocklayered.js file

```
function addSlider(type, data, unit, format)
{
    sliderList.push({
        type: type,
        data: data,
        unit: unit,
        format: format
    });
}

function initSliders()
{
    $(sliderList).each(function(i, slider){
        $('#layered_'+slider['type']+'_slider').slider(slider['data']);

        var from = '';
        var to = '';
        switch (slider['format'])
        {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
                from = blocklayeredFormatCurrency($('#layered_'+slider['type']+'_slider').slider('values', 0), slider['format'], slider['unit']);
                to = blocklayeredFormatCurrency($('#layered_'+slider['type']+'_slider').slider('values', 1), slider['format'], slider['unit']);
                break;
            case 5:
                from =  $('#layered_'+slider['type']+'_slider').slider('values', 0)+slider['unit']
                to = $('#layered_'+slider['type']+'_slider').slider('values', 1)+slider['unit'];
                break;
        }
        $('#layered_'+slider['type']+'_range').html(from+' - '+to);
    });
}
```

Comment: The blocklayered configuration allows, without any changes to code, to show the price like a range slider, how you get this error? Have you made changes to code?

Comment: Your answer shed the light on the right problem. Earlier I've made custom hook to display blocklayered above the products instead of the left side but have only hidden blocklayered in the left column using css instead of simply unhooking it. Because of the double blocklayered module on the same page slider didn't work properly

Comment: Problem solved now?

Comment: Yeah i just unhooked blocklayered from left column and now it works fine